# I am trying to start a grails project in debug mode, it doesn't start

Tags: debugging, ggts

I am trying to start a grails project in debug mode, it doesn't start
The grails debug config looks like

```
grails> -Dserver.port=8091 run-app
```

i have also tried

```
grails> -Dserver.port=8091 --debug run-app
```

But no success. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **--debug** use **--debug-fork** to run your app in debug mode:

```
grails --debug-fork -Dserver.port=8091 run-app
```

Comment: I tried this but server is not at all starting, if I try from command line server starts but debug points are not hit

Comment: @omkarnathbag append --stacktrace to the command and copy the errors that you are getting.

Comment: no errors or exception are displayed. the console is blank

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use remote debugging.

Add this to your BuildConfig.groovy file:

`grails.project.fork = [
        // configure settings for the run-app JVM
        run    : [
                  maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: true, 
                  maxPerm: 256, forkReserve: false
                 ]
]`

Next configure remote debugging in yor IDE with host: localhost and port: 5005

After that run application using run-app command and when it tells in console:

> Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005

Run your configured remote debugger. When application starts you will be able to debug your code.